# Delete a non-ascii character, only if a condition applies, in bash

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, hex

I have a very specific need, for which I've been trying to solve, without success.

I have a log, which is created by a dump of a tcp/ip socket... It converts the Hex to ASCII, but naturally there are some special characters in it.

I've managed to remove them, but I'm currently experiencing a difficulty: Sometimes, an 0x0A is sent, which messes with my applications... I'm trying to remove it, but then it also removes the valid 0x0A at the end of the line...

Basically, I have, in the log file:

```
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String}
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={
Teste String2}
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={
Teste String3}
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String4}
```

I want the final result as

```
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String}
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String2}
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String3}
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String4}
```

The characters are always between {}, so every 0x0A after the } is valid, but inside is not.

every command I've tried either removes all the 0x0A, or just not work at all.

I've tried things like

```
sed 's/^[^}]*}//'
sed 's/\x0A$//'
```

any thoughts?

Comment: Are you applying the sed command on the ASCII text or on the hex?

Comment: On the ASCII text...

Answer (score 3):

Another *simpler* `awk`:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (/}/ ? ORS : "")}' file

08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String}
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String2}
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String3}
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String4}
```

This `awk` command checks presence of `}` in a line and then only prints line break, otherwise it prints record without line break.

Comment: This is awesome.

Comment: Yes, it should have been `ORS` :)

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible with sed, but it's easier to read and understand in awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS=FS="{"; ORS=RS="}" } { sub(/[^[:print:]]/,"",$2) } 1' input.txt
```

**What does this do?**

- First, we set our input and output field separators to `{`, and our input and output record separators to `}`. This lets us predictably grab the bracketed text as a specific field (at least based on your sample data).
- Next, we replace any non-printable characters in field #2 with a null string, eliminating newlines, backspaces, etc.
- Finally, we print the line using awk shorthand.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS we can just isolate each `{...}` string and remove newlines within it:

```
$ awk -v RS='{[^}]+}' '{ORS=gensub(/\n/,"","g",RT)}1' file
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String}
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String2}
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String3}
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String4}
```

For this specific case the other awk answers will work just fine, the above is just a more general solution to the problem of isolating a delimited string to then perform operations on it like removing characters as in this case.

Answer (score 0):

**With sed**:

Linux:

```
$ sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s/(\{[^}]*)\\n([^{]*\})/\1\2/g' file
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String}
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String2}
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String3}
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String4}
```

FreeBSD and macOS:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N;$!ba' -e 's/(\{[^}]*)\\n([^{]*\})/\1\2/g' file
```

---

**Explanations**

`-e ':a' -e 'N;$!ba'` allows us to consider both the current and the next line on each iteration of sed. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/6884590) for details.

`(\{[^}]*)` ensures there's an opening brace not followed by a closing one.

`([^{]*\})` does the opposite.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in FreeBSD or macOS. Is this GNU-sed specific?

Comment: Works when you split it up: `sed -E -e ':a' -e 'N;$!ba' -e 's/(\{[^}]*)\n([^{]*\})/\1\2/g'` .. non-GNU sed appears to want labels not to be followed by semicolons.

Comment: @ghoti Thanks. I updated. This should work with both GNU-sed and non-GNU-sed (?).

Comment: `\n` is not portable across sed versions (you need backslash followed by a literal newline for portability) and `-E` will only work in GNU and OSX sed while `-r` will only work in GNU sed.

Comment: Also, sed in Solaris 10 does not support `-E` or `-r`, so a BRE-based solution would be preferred for maximum portability. In bash, you may be able to get the embedded literal newline using format substitution, i.e `$'foo\nbar'`.

Comment: And at the end of the day this simply isn't a job for sed at all since an awk solution will be clearer, simpler, more efficient, more portable, easier to enhance/maintain, etc. so why bother polishing it?

Answer (score 0):

Perl:

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/({[^}]*)\x0A([^}]*})/\1\2/g' file
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String}
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String2}
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String3}
08-14-2017 10:00:00 String={Teste String4}
```

Pure Bash (based on anubhava's awk):

```
while IFS="\n" read -r line; do 
    le=""
    [[ $line =~ \} ]] && le=$'\n'
    printf "%s%s" "$line" "$le"
done <file
```